# how to dismiss instantiated navigation rootviewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Below is my working code which I have used to instantiate my viewController

```
let myPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as! myViewController

        let myNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myPage)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myNav
```

Could anyone help and provide a solution to dismiss myViewController?

Comment: why you want to dismiss the root view controller ? are you making another VC as root view ?

Comment: I just want to dismiss currentViewController and go back to my previous screen and for that yes I will make my previous screen as root view.

Comment: you can simply use self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: Tried again but nothing happens. It's not dismissing currentViewController

Comment: if you want to dismiss your current VC and go back to root VC, use popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: In my case, I am want to dismiss my current viewController which is my root V as well. I have tried this: self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) but not working. Not sure whats the problem here :(

Comment: you can only have one root VC at any point. You said you want to go to your previous screen, so i assume you previous screen is your root VC. If you made your current VC as root VC then you can't dismiss it. You need to make your previous VC root view again and present it

Comment: I am new to swift, can you provide me some sample code to  to make previous VC root view again and present it. Thanks!

Comment: Set your viewController to the rootViewController and then dismiss.